# CSS ou JQuery para animação

Tags: javascript, css, animação

Em se tratando de animação, qual devo usar? Qual é o mais leve? É possível fazer a mesmas animações tanto em um quanto no outro?

Comment: Reabri a pergunta pois existem maneiras objetivas de responder (mesmo a resposta de uma ou duas das 3 dúvidas sendo "depende").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CSS3 é sempre mais leve.

No entanto você pode enfrentar situações mais complexas onde uma simples estrutura de `animation` ou `transition` não será tão útil.

Na maioria dos casos é possível intercalar o jQuery/JavaScript com classes CSS3 (animation ou transitions simples).

Exemplo de uso de JS + CSS3 keyframes;

```js
document.getElementById('element').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('bounceIn');
}, false);
```

```css
#element {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.animated { 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
    animation-duration: 1s; 
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; 
    animation-fill-mode: both; 
} 

@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn { 
    0% { 
        opacity: 0; 
        -webkit-transform: scale(.3); 
    } 

    50% { 
        opacity: 1; 
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05); 
    } 

    70% { 
        -webkit-transform: scale(.9); 
    } 

    100% { 
         -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
    } 
} 

@keyframes bounceIn { 
    0% { 
        opacity: 0; 
        transform: scale(.3); 
    } 

    50% { 
        opacity: 1; 
        transform: scale(1.05); 
    } 

    70% { 
        transform: scale(.9); 
    } 

    100% { 
        transform: scale(1); 
    } 
} 

.bounceIn { 
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn; 
    animation-name: bounceIn; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="element" class="animated" >clique aqui</div>
```

O script acima apenas faz um `toggle` (com JS) da classe animada com CSS3 animation. Seria perfeitamente possível fazer o mesmo apenas com jQuery, mas *seria um tanto mais pesado*!

Veja outro exemplo onde, para o nosso objetivo, só é possível usar jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var items = [["Two",2000], ["Three",3000], ["Four",4000], ["Five",5000], ["Six",6000], ["One",1000]];
  var $text = $('#div1 span');

  function loop(index) {
    $text.html(items[index][0]);
    $text.fadeIn();
    $text.delay(items[index][1]).fadeOut(function(){
        if(index < (items.length - 1)){
            loop(++index);
        }
        else loop(0);
    });
  }

  loop(0);
});
```

```css
#div1{float:left;padding:20px;margin-top:40px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"><span></span>-free Recipes</div>
```

No exemplo acima o script jQuery faz uma transição de textos(em array) dentro de um elemento. Cada transição dura o tempo determinado no primeiro index de cada array dentro do array pai.

Isso só é possível graças ao callback do método `fadeOut()` onde a função chama a si mesmo a cada iteração.

**Resumindo**: você deve usar CSS3 sempre que for possível, quando não for, intercale com jQuery/Javascript e se não der pra intercalar use jQuery.

Comment: @Mathdesigner47, se essa resposta atendeu suas espectativas, poderia marcá-la como certa.

Answer (score 6):

O mais leve é uma animação utilizando apenas CSS, porém em alguns casos é necessário utilizar Javascript para controlar o comportamento da Animação e isto acrescenta um custo adicional na execução da sua animação, pois basicamente o seu Script irá manipular dinamicamente os styles do elemento.

Comment: Leia este post: http://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/ . Sua resposta não está devidamente completa e correta.

Comment: Leitura interessante, realmente Um Myth Busting, porém as comparações envolvem Animações otimizadas utilizando Javascript e o "jQuery Factory", desta forma ainda é seguro dizer que CSS é mais rápido do que jQuery, mais ainda teríamos optimized javascript vs CSS, e recai a pergunta... Quantos de nós temos as skills para utilizar Javascript a este nível e saber quando é melhor usar JS ou CSS? Mas muito obrigado pela sugestão de leitura.

Comment: Sim, sei que alguns não tem as habilidades para isso, mas com a leitura da pra perceber que o CSS ainda tem algumas limitações em relação a JS.

Comment: @Natan Excelente esse artigo! Você devia escrever uma resposta baseada nele ;)