# Animação não está fluida

Tags: javascript

Opa galera tenho uma div que é meu cabeçalho do site, quero esconder ele ao clicar em um botão e fazer ele aparecer ao clicar em outro botão. Consigo fazer esconder e a movimentação está do jeito que quero, contudo na hora de fazer aparecer de volta não apresenta a mesma fluidez e a imagem não fica na tela, sumindo ao final.

```js
function myMove() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("box-toogle"); 
    var pos = 0;
 var t = 0;
 var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
    function frame() {
        if (pos == 160) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            pos--; 
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
    t++;
        }
}

function myMove1() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("box-toogle"); 
    var pos = 150;
 var t = 0;
 var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
    function frame() {
        if (pos == 0) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            pos--; 
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
    t++;
        }
}
```

```css
#box-toogle {
 width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
<header id="box-toogle">texto</header>
 </body>
</html>
```

Sou iniciante em javascript, se puderem me ajudar agradeço

Comment: olhando o seu código, os métodos `myMove` e `myMove1` não tem a ultima `}` para encerrar o método, faça a correção e teste novamente.

Comment: As suas funções não estão fechadas, cada uma falta um chaves no final. Aconselho utilizar uma boa IDE para programar, a qual faz highlight nos códigos e ajuda a visualização e percepção destes erros básicos, Netbeans é uma delas.

Comment: Opa me desculpem na hora de copiar e colar acabei esquecendo a ultima  chave, no meu código está fechado certinho e continua não fluido, alterarei o código aqui colado para ficar de acordo. aguardo o parecer de vocês obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este tipo de animações devem ser feitas com CSS.

Nesse caso só precisas de

```
#box-toogle {
    // ...

    top: 0px;
    transition: top 1s;
}

#box-toogle.escondido {
    top: -100px;
}
```

e quando o elemento for clicado adicionas ou removes essa classe `escondido`.

Exemplo:

```js
var header = document.getElementById('box-toogle');
header.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('escondido');
});
```

```css
#box-toogle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
 border: 2px #ddf solid;
 font-size: 80px;
 
 top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    transition: top 1s;
}

#box-toogle.escondido {
    top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<header id="box-toogle">texto</header>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zdt1vced/

Comment: Sergio muito obrigado, não sei se é uma dúvida de novato mas não consigo fazer funcionar o código que me passaste no jsFiddle executa tranquilamente, agora quando passo para o notepad e executo no navegador o mesmo não acontece, copiei e colei igual me passaste preciso fazer + alguma alteração?

Outra coisa sabes me dizer pq não é recomendado fazer efeitos assim apenas no js?, obrigado imensamente.

Comment: @VeteranoKuno1 sobre CSS vs JS dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51542/129

Comment: @VeteranoKuno1 em relação a não funcionar na tua página, coloca o JavaScript no final da página. Se não funcionar coloca aqui um pastebin com a página toda.

Comment: Sérgio realmente colocando no final da página funcionou, não entendi pq não funcionou em um js externo. Amolando você um pouquinho + e com preguiça de pesquisar aqui no fórum qual livro você recomenda, estou usando o codeAcademy para aprender o básico + já sinto necessidade de  outras alternativas, abraço e muito obrigado, mesmo!

Comment: @VeteranoKuno1 ainda bem que funcionou. Se quiseres podes marcar a resposta como aceite. Estás a precisar de uma função onload para o código só correr quando a página carrega. Se colocares o teu código dentro de `window.onload = function () { ... };` já deve funcionar num fcheiro externo também. Ou então coloca a tag `<script>` no final do body.